# Not installed Firebase Analytics saying that 'FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist' xcode 8 swift 3

Tags: firebase, swift3, cocoapods, xcode8, firebase-analytics

I have just add some pod like pod 'FacebookLogin' pod 'Google/SignIn' and run my project. In terminal project automatically adds the firebase frameworks too even i don't wanna use them. And second thing is that firebase analytics giving an error image is giving below!!

I have even uninstalled app from simulator many times. and cleaned project.

I appreciate Your Answers..Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not an error. It's just a message to tell you that the SDK does have proxy and if you don't like it, it's a way to disable the feature. If you don't want to use Firebase Analytics SDK, follow this documented [steps](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics) to disable it entirely:

> If you need to deactivate Analytics collection permanently in a
>   version of your app, set FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_DEACTIVATED to
>   YES in your app's Info.plist file.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Alex D: but in my info.plist there is no option of FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_DEACTIVATED infact i don't wanna use firebase. then how can i solve this?

Comment: You can add a new key-value in your Info.plist (not GoogleService-Info.plist) by clicking the plus button and add a new boolean key-value pair.